# Cygwin gcc compiling and running, but doesn't printf anything

Tags: c, windows, gcc, cygwin

I'm just starting with C and installed Cygwin with GCC compiler on Windows. I tried running this Hello World program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{

    //fflush(stdout);
    //setlinebuf(stdout);
    //setbuf(stdout, 0);
    printf("Hello World!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

The code compiles fine but when I try running it with `./` there is no output. I have tried to fix it using the commented lines (obviously I uncommented before running) but still had no output.

Comment: Show the command you use to compile and the command you use to run; it is likely there is something wrong with one of those two as the code itself looks fine.

Comment: try this as first instruction in your `main` function:
```setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);```

Comment: The command I use to compile is `gcc HelloWorld.c` then I run `a.exe` in Command Line or `./a.exe` in Cygwin. I tried `setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);` but it didn't work either.

Comment: Can it be that you edit one source file, but compile and run another? Try to do a syntax error whether it breaks the compilation.

Comment: Hmm. I think you have something pretty strange going on. Try this from bash (in cygwin): `gcc -oa.exe && ./a.exe`

Comment: I don't get it. Where did 'a.exe' come from?

Comment: Tried the syntax error, didn't work. Tried `gcc HelloWorld.c -oa.exe && ./a.exe`, didn't work. a.exe is basically the default compiled file (I think).

Comment: usually you specify the output file with the -o parameter, could I suggest you try the following to see the full debug information; gcc -Wall -o b.exe HelloWorld.c and then ./b.exe

Answer (score 1):

Name your source code file **hello.c**. In Cygwin bash shell, go to the directory where the source file hello.c is. Run `gcc -o hello.exe hello.c`. This will produce the executable **hello.exe** in the same directory. Then run `./hello`.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

this may be due to dll missing

add the cygwin dlls in your path, i.e.

```
d:\cygwin1.7.9[1]\cygwin\bin\
```

Comment: Correct. It is either the **absence** or **presence** of one of Cygwin's DLLs. In my case, i run the `gcc` command in a directory where I had some of Cygwin's DLLs copied over because I was trying to debug a `JNI` issue and I had to copy the DLLs into the folder for `Intellij IDE` to partially work. Thanks to this answer. I simply `mkdir xxx; cp app.c xxx;` and then do my `gcc` in that new folder.